# Updating values in weird list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have the following data structure:

`fields = [{'key': 'ADDRESS1', 'value': None}, {'key': 'ADDRESS2', 'value': None}]`

Please note, the structure of this data is outside of my control. But I have to work with it.

How would I go about updating the `value` "key" the `Object` where the `key` "key" is equal to, say `'ADDRESS1'`, such that I would have the following after manipulation:

N.B. The update has to update the value based off of the `key`, not the index of the object - as this is loosely defined.

`fields = [{'key': 'ADDRESS1', 'value': 'Some Address Value'}, {'key': 'ADDRESS2', 'value': None}]`

Comment: I have some trouble understanding what excatly you are trying to say. Could you try and rephrase it?
Also, I would think `fields[0]['value'] = 'Some Address Value'`

Comment: What should happen if more than one dict has an "ADDRESS1" key? Just update all of them?

Comment: Assumption is that there will not be duplicate `keys`.

Comment: I'd suggest you `fields_dict = {el['key'] = el['value'] for el in fields}` and then work with `fields_dict`. Now you simply have a `dict`. To revert back, simply `fields = [{'key': k, 'value': v} for k, v in fields_dict.items()]`.

Comment: mind my type-o: it's `fields_dict = {el['key']: el['value'] for el in fields}`, so `:` not `=` (pointed out by @Kevin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d_list = [{'key': 'ADDRESS1', 'value': None}, {'key': 'ADDRESS2', 'value': None}] 

for d in d_list:
    if d['key'] == 'ADDRESS1':
        d['value'] = 'Some Address Value'

>>> d_list

[{'key': 'ADDRESS1', 'value': 'Some Address Value'}, {'key': 'ADDRESS2', 'value': None}]
```

**EDIT**: removed list comp as per suggestion in comments

Comment: This looks like the correct output. You could perhaps do it a little more concisely with `for d in d_list: if d['key'] == 'ADDRESS1': d['value'] = 'Some Address Value'`

Comment: @Kevin, you're right the list comp is pretty extra and actually probably slower in this case

Answer (score 2):

Brian Joseph's approach works well if you only plan on changing one value. But if you want to make a lot of changes, you might get tired of writing a loop and conditional for each change. In that case you may be better off converting your data structure into an ordinary dict, making your changes to that, and converting back to a weird-list-of-dicts at the end.

```
d_list = [{'key': 'ADDRESS1', 'value': None}, {'key': 'ADDRESS2', 'value': None}]
d = {x["key"]: x["value"] for x in d_list}

d["ADDRESS1"] = 'Some Address Value'
d["new_key"] = "foo"

new_d_list = [{"key": k, "value": v} for k,v in d.items()]
print(new_d_list)
```

Result:

```
[{'key': 'ADDRESS1', 'value': 'Some Address Value'}, {'key': 'ADDRESS2', 'value': None}, {'key': 'new_key', 'value': 'foo'}]
```

(Final ordering of the dicts may vary when using a Python version lower than 3.6)

Comment: @jojo, yes, I saw your comment and thought it was a nice approach, although the syntax needed little tweaking. I apologize for not crediting you directly in the post.

Comment: indeed, `=`->`:`

Comment: This was my first approach - to make a dictionary of the key <=> value 'keys', (confusing), then converting it back. I may utilise this answer in my final approach.