# How to check if 'x' is in a dict value and if so print the dict associated

Tags: python

I am searching a list of dicts to see if the code is found within one of the dictionary values, what I want to do is print out the dictionary associated to that code, if it finds it within the list.

I have the following (print statements are there to show what I want to do).

```
if any(d['Code'] == responsecode for d in list_of_dicts):
    print(d)
```

the LOD would be like:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'Code':'2345', 'Message':'the message'},
    {'Code':'1111', 'Message':'the message'}
]
```

Response Code would be something like: `1111`

Comment: So you have a list of dictionaries, and you go through each of them to find the key called "Code"?

Comment: Coincidentally, your data is similarly structured to a question from yesterday: [Updating values in weird list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58646468/953482). You could use my answer to create a regular dict, and then you can just do `if responsecode in regular_dict: print(responsecode, regular_dict[responsecode])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generator expression with `if` to filter the dicts, take its [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) value, use the raised exception if nothing is found as `if`/`else` replacement:

```
try:
    print(next(d for d in list_of_dicts if d['Code'] == responsecode))
except StopIteration:
    print('Not found')
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I couldn't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension as a filter:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'Code':'2345', 'Message':'the message'},{'Code':'1111', 'Message':'the message'}]

responsecode  = '1111'

found = [d for d in list_of_dicts if d.get('Code1',None) == responsecode]

print(found)
```

Output:

```
[{'Code': '1111', 'Message': 'the message'}]
```

or for `responsecode  = 'foo'`

```
[]
```